# Applying twice for Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I already have a Schengen Visa and will return home in March.

Can I apply for a Schengen visa again in April and come back in April for another 3 months? Or is there a way to extend Schengen Visa  for another 3 months?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What citizenship do you hold?  What Schengen visa type do you currently hold?

Answer (score 2):

Visa and length of stay are two separate (albeit obviously related) issues. Short stays in the Schengen area are limited to 90 days in any 180-day period (see the [relevant discussion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule)) so if you stay there for three months, you need to be somewhere else for three more months before you can come back on a short-stay visa.

Depending on your exact situation, you might or might not be able to get a new Schengen visa but it will not open any right to stay longer. Some people can visit the Schengen area without visa, others have short-stay visas valid for several years but they all have to abide by this rule. It also doesn't matter which country issued the visa or if you get a new short-stay visa from a different country than the one that issued your first visa.

The only way to stay longer legally is to obtain a national long-stay (type D) visa or, in exceptional cases, a limited territorial validity visa (and exceptional means exceptional, it's intended for diplomats participating in talks at the UN and these sorts of things).

If you do want to apply for a new visa, two things are worth noting:

- You can't apply for a new Schengen short-stay visa if you already have a valid one, you first have to get the old one invalidated by the country that originally issued it.
- If you already used up your 90 days or submit an itinerary that would run afoul of that rule, your visa should be denied. This denial will be registered in a database and the visa application fee will not be refunded so trying on the off-chance that it might work is not necessarily a good idea.